Passing string from VB6 to c++ to C#, string is cut off
I have VB6 code, which cannot be changed, calling functions from an external dll. I am replacing the external dll with a C++ dll which I'm writing, which will call a .NET dll which I'm writing, via COM. I have control over the C++ and C#.
VB6 calls the dll functions like so:
Declare Sub IEsend _
    Lib "IEEE_32M1.DLL" _
    Alias "_ieee_send@16" (ByVal addr As Long, _
                           ByVal s As String, _
                           ByVal l As Long, _
                           status As Long)

C# exposing functions via COM for C++ to call
namespace IEEE_32MCOM
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("41C9877D-C110-4CBC-9E1B-4507D220DBCD")]
    public interface IIEEE_32MCOM
    {
        void _ieee_sendCOM(int addr, string s, int l, ref int status);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [Guid("FE506B77-AD6B-4C37-97E2-A7A5DDE0CA52")]
    public class IEEE_32MCOMClass : IIEEE_32MCOM
    {
        public void _ieee_sendCOM(int addr, string s, int l, ref int status)
        {
            // .NET stuff here
        }
    }
}

C++ header
#pragma once
#include <string>
#import "IEEE_32MCOM.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, named_guids

extern "C"
{
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:ieee_send=_ieee_send@16")
    __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall ieee_send(long addr, BSTR cmd, long l, long* status);
}

IEEE_32MCOM::IIEEE_32MCOM* myInterface;

void init();

C++ code file
#pragma comment(lib, "IEEE_32MCOM.tlb")
#include "pch.h"
#include "IEEE_32M1.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void _ieee_sendCOM(long addr, BSTR cmd, long l, long* status);

void __stdcall ieee_send(long addr, BSTR cmd, long l, long* status)
{
    init();
    myInterface->_ieee_sendCOM(addr, cmd, l, status);
}

void init()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        __uuidof(IEEE_32MCOM::IEEE_32MCOMClass),
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL,
        IEEE_32MCOM::IID_IIEEE_32MCOM,
        (void**)&myInterface);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        _com_error e(hr);
    }
}

The call chain is working after much research - I am not fluent in C++.
Except the issue is that strings being passed from VB6 seem to 8-bit characters, and the BSTR in C++ is rendering as 16-bit characters.
Passing the 9 character string "ABCDEFGHI",
C++ sees 䉁䑃䙅䡇I
C# sees 䉁䑃䙅䡇
I don't mind converting to a human readable string in C#, actually I prefer it. But as can be seen, the last character is missing from the string in C#
Inspecting the bytes, var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s); yields 8 bytes which include the first 8 characters, 65, 66, ..., 72, missing the final char 73, or "I".
I believe I am restricted to BSTR for COM, but it's cutting off a character when the number of characters is odd. How do I pass the entire string to .NET? I would prefer the entire human readable string get passed from C++ to C# in the first place but any way I can make this work is fine.

Show how you are creating tand passing around the BSTR it likely starts there. "I am replacing the external dll with a C++ dll which I'm writing, which will call a .NET dll which I'm writing" why not just create a C# dll and call it directly from VB6?

@Charlieface because of the calling convention in VB6 using the stdcall decorations. I can't modify the vb6 code. Otherwise if I could I would use COM there

Do you have a small reproducing project

C# can use StdCall, why would you think otherwise? COM works fine from VB6 to C#. And why does this need COM, why not just use DllExport https://github.com/3F/DllExport

@Charlieface still learning. I haven't needed to do something like this before. I know COM works from vb6 to C#, but I need import a function as the VB6 is doing, and all my research pointed to no, a .NET assembly won't have a suitable entrypoint to be called that way. Maybe the github project you linked handles everything

@SimonMourier There are three projects involved but not public. I am actually exposing 7 functions but I've only included one in the question - enough to show this behavior.

See some background on VBA/VB6 and strings here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43423527/403671 also from C# you're supposed to use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bstr)] to decorate BSTR arguments

@SimonMourier Thank you. I did try at one point [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bstr)] but the tooltip stated it was default for COM so I didn't bother keeping it. The issue was on the C++ side


Except the issue is that strings being passed from VB6 seem to 8-bit characters, and the BSTR in C++ is rendering as 16-bit characters.

That is exactly what is happening.  So, you need to change your DLL to not accept the string as a BSTR, but rather as a char*, and then convert it to BSTR/wchar_t* when passing it to C#.
For example:
void __stdcall ieee_send(long addr, const char* cmd, long l, long* status)
{
    init();
    myInterface->_ieee_sendCOM(addr, _bstr_t(cmd), l, status);
}


The VB6 should have been Declare Unicode Sub IEsend, alternatively use StrPtr to grab the BSTR pointer and pass it directly, but OP says they can't modify this.

@Charlieface It was built in 2013 and although I have the code, I can't recompile

If the string in a different function is passed by reference, how do I handle that?

@djv see Microsoft_KB 187912 - ByVal string will pass as a char*, whereas ByRef string will pass as a char** (C) / char*& (C++)

I see, I will need to pass a BSTR* to C#, and _bstr_t(cmd) doesn't give me one. I'll also need to convert it back to char*& to pass it back to VB. I'm hung up on that, shall I make a new question?

ATL::CComBSTR will allocate a BSTR (in "COM" memory) and you can construct that from a std::wstring

@djv your C# code is expecting a string by value not by reference. Your C++ code can pass it a wchar_t* pointer (which BSTR is compatible with), not a BSTR* pointer. On the VB side, the char* it gives your C++ code points to a buffer that you can write data back to VB.

@RemyLebeau that's perfect, thanks so much. Wish I could give you another +1
